# Beginners Java Project: Basic Pokedex using if-else statements. Suggestions?

Tags: java, if-statement, project

Our instructor told us to create a basic Java program using everything we've learned in class thus far (basic prints, selection structures, looping, GUI, arrays, etc) and being a Pokemon fan, I decided to make a basic GUI Pokedex that lets the user search for the details of a particular starter Pokemon. This program also asks the user if he wants to search by Pokemon type or by region of origin, just in case the user does not know the name of the Pokemon.

Here is the code I came up with and it runs:
(**WARNING: Really long.**)

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class StarterPokedex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String choice, desc=null, pokemon=null, searchBy=null, region=null, type=null, pokeNo=null, species=null, habitat=null; 

        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you know the name of the Starter Pokemon you are looking for? (Yes/No)", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", 3); 
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name of the Starter Pokemon: ", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            searchBy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Search by: 'type' or 'region'?", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", 3);

                if (searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
                    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter pokemon type: (Fire/Water/Grass)", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Fire")) {
                    pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are fire-type: \n\nCharmander \nCyndaquil \nTorchic \nChimchar \nTepig \nFennekin \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Fire-type Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Water")) {
                        pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are water-type: \n\nSquirtle \nTotodile \nMudkip \nPiplup \nOshawott \nFroakie \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Water-type Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Grass")) {
                        pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are grass-type: \n\nBulbasaur \nChikorita \nTreecko \nTurtwig \nSnivy \nChespin \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Grass-type Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }

                        else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered an invalid keyword. Try again.", "Error!", 1); }
                    }


                else if (searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("region")) {
                    region = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter region: (Kanto/Johto/Hoenn/Sinnoh/Unova/Kalos)", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 

                    if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Kanto")) {
                    pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Kanto region: \n\nBulbasaur \nCharmander \nSquirtle \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Kanto Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Johto")) {
                            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Johto region: \n\nChikorita \nCyndaquil \nTotodile \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Johto Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Hoenn")) {
                            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Hoenn region: \n\nTreecko \nTorchic \nMudkip \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Hoenn Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Sinnoh")) {
                            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Sinnoh region: \n\nTurtwig \nChimchar \nPiplup \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Sinnoh Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Unova")) {
                            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Unova region: \n\nSnivy \nTepig \nOshawott \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Unova Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }
                        else if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("Kalos")) {
                            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Here are the list of Starter Pokemon that are from the Kalos region: \n\nChespin \nFennekin \nFroakie \n\nWhich Pokemon would you like to search?", "Kalos Starter Pokemon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); }

                        else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered an invalid keyword. Try again.", "Error!", 1); }

                }

            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered an invalid keyword. Try again.", "Error!", 1); }

        }

        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You entered an invalid keyword. Try again.", "Error!", 1);


        if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Bulbasaur")) {
            region="Kanto";
            pokeNo="001";
            species="Seed";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Grassland";
            desc="A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Charmander")) {
            region="Kanto";
            pokeNo="004";
            species="Lizard";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Mountain";
            desc="Obviously prefers hot places. When it rains, steam is said to spout from the tip of its tail.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Squirtle")) {
            region="Kanto";
            pokeNo="007";
            species="Tiny turtle";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Water's-edge";
            desc="After birth, its back swells and hardens into a shell. Powerfully sprays foam from its mouth.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Chikorita")) {
            region="Johto";
            pokeNo="152";
            species="Leaf";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Grassland";
            desc="A sweet aroma gently wafts from the leaf on its head. It is docile and loves to soak up the sun's rays.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Cyndaquil")) {
            region="Johto";
            pokeNo="155";
            species="Fire Mouse";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Grassland";
            desc="It is timid, and always curls itself up in a ball. If attacked, it flares up its back for protection.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Totodile")) {
            region="Johto";
            pokeNo="158";
            species="Big Jaw";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Water's-edge";
            desc="Its well-developed jaws are powerful and capable of crushing anything. Even its trainer must be careful.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Treecko")) {
            region="Hoenn";
            pokeNo="252";
            species="Wood Gecko";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Forest";
            desc="Its well-developed jaws are powerful and capable of crushing anything. Even its trainer must be careful.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Torchic")) {
            region="Hoenn";
            pokeNo="255";
            species="Chick";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Grassland";
            desc="A fire burns inside, so it feels very warm to hug. It launches fireballs of 1,800 degrees F.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Mudkip")) {
            region="Hoenn";
            pokeNo="258";
            species="Mud Fish";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Water's-edge";
            desc="The fin on MUDKIP's head acts as highly sensitive radar. Using this fin to sense movements of water and air, this POKÉMON can determine what is taking place around it without using its eyes.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Turtwig")) {
            region="Sinnoh";
            pokeNo="387";
            species="Tiny Leaf";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Lake-side";
            desc="It undertakes photosynthesis with its body, making oxygen. The leaf on its head wilts if it is thirsty.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Chimchar")) {
            region="Sinnoh";
            pokeNo="390";
            species="Chimp";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Mountain";
            desc="Its fiery rear end is fueled by gas made in its belly. Even rain can't extinguish the fire.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Piplup")) {
            region="Sinnoh";
            pokeNo="393";
            species="Penguin";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Arctic";
            desc="A poor walker, it often falls down. However, its strong pride makes it puff up its chest without a care.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Snivy")) {
            region="Unova";
            pokeNo="495";
            species="Grass Snake";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Forest";
            desc="It is very intelligent and calm. Being exposed to lots of sunlight makes its movements swifter.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Tepig")) {
            region="Unova";
            pokeNo="498";
            species="Fire Pig";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Grassland";
            desc="It can deftly dodge its foe's attacks while shooting fireballs from its nose. It roasts berries before it eats them.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Oshawott")) {
            region="Unova";
            pokeNo="501";
            species="Sea Otter";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Unknown";
            desc="The scalchop on its stomach isn't just used for battle - it can be used to break open hard berries as well.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Chespin")) {
            region="Kalos";
            pokeNo="650";
            species="Spiny Nut";
            type="Grass";
            habitat="Unknown";
            desc="The quills on its head are usually soft. When it flexes them, the points become so hard and sharp that they can pierce rock.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Fennekin")) {
            region="Kalos";
            pokeNo="653";
            species="Fox";
            type="Fire";
            habitat="Unknown";
            desc="Eating a twig fills it with energy, and its roomy ears give vent to air hotter than 390 degrees Fahrenheit.";
            }

            else if (pokemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Froakie")) {
            region="Kalos";
            pokeNo="656";
            species="Foam Frog";
            type="Water";
            habitat="Unknown";
            desc="It secretes flexible bubbles from its chest and back. The bubbles reduce the damage it would otherwise take when attacked.";
            }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such Starter Pokemon exists. Try again."); }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pokemon: " + pokemon + "\nRegion: " + region + "\nNational Pokemon #: " + pokeNo + "\nSpecies: " + species + "\nType: " + type + "\nHabitat: " + habitat + "\nDescription: " + desc, "Pokedex Results", 1);


        }

    }
```

I just wanted to ask for suggestions on how to improve this code. I know it looks sort of messy and I really wanted to make use of arrays, except for a program like this, it seems that I would be needing tables, but we haven't discussed that in class yet and we were advised not to get ahead of ourselves lol.

I wanted to use loops for this too, to make it a little more complex, but I have no idea where I can fit all that in.

Also, this is a really huge bulk of codes (the longest code I've written so far), and I am aware that in Java, the simpler the code, the more efficient it is to use. Is there any way I can simplify this code without having to stray from the basics and still getting my desired output?

P.S.
If you spot any mistakes, PLEASE feel free to correct them.

Comment: _"I just wanted to ask for suggestions on how to improve this code"_. Better suit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Does the program work like you want it to? If so, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: At the very least, you'll want to look into [`switch` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of the massive number of `else if`s.

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, the code works just fine. I wasn't aware of the existence of Code Review. Many thanks!

Comment: @admdrew I tried, but somehow switch statements won't let me use Strings. I tried parsing and using enum but I thought this would have been easier.

Answer (score 2):

Go and have a look at Objects, and Object Orientated Programming. What you would normally do would be create a load of objects, storing the details about each Pokemon inside it, and you would then search through these to find those that matched the criteria. This would mean when you added another Pokemon, you just add them into the list, and your searches should work right away.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 1):

One way to perhaps do it: 
Create a Element object and a Pokémon object (perhaps as a subclass?) That holds the necessary information. You could also create Region object. In order to avoid so many if/else/switch statements, you could place everything into arrays/array list/maps. You can simply call some sort of method to return the appropriate pokemon/element/region. I believe this will clean the code up a lot.

I was able to simplify this a lot just by adding the **Pokemon** class. Granted there are still a lot of things I would change with this code personally, I think the following is a good start for you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StarterPokedex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Pokemon> p = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();
        String choice, pokemon = "", searchBy, region, type, list = "", str = "";

        p.add(new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "Kanto", 1, "Seed", "Grass", "Grassland", 
            "A strange seed was planted on its back at birth."
            +" The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon."));
            p.add(new Pokemon("Charmander", "Johto", 2, "Seed", "Fire", "Grassland", 
            "A strange seed was planted on its back at birth."
            +" The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon."));
            p.add(new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Kanto", 3, "Seed", "Water", "Grassland", 
            "A strange seed was planted on its back at birth."
            +" The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon."));

        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Do you know the name of the Starter Pokemon you are looking for?"
            + "(Yes/No)", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", 3); 

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter the name of the Starter Pokemon: ",
            "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            searchBy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Search by: 'type' or 'region'?", "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!",
                3);

                if (searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
                    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter pokemon type: (Fire/Water/Grass)",
                    "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
                        if (p.get(i).getType().equals(type)) {
                            list = list + p.get(i).getName() + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                    pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, list,
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                } else if (searchBy.equalsIgnoreCase("region")) {
                    region = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter region: (Kanto/Johto/Hoenn/Sinnoh/Unova/Kalos)",
                    "Welcome to the Starter Pokedex!",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
                        if (p.get(i).getRegion().equals(region)) {
                            list = list + p.get(i).getName() + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                    pokemon = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, list,
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            if (p.get(i).getName().equals(pokemon)) {
                str =  p.get(i).toString();
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "Pokedex Results", 1);


        }

    }
```

And here is the pokemon class.

```
public class Pokemon {

    private String name;
    private String region;
    private int pokeNumber;
    private String species;
    private String type;
    private String habitat;
    private String description;

    public Pokemon(String name, String region, int pokeNumber, String species,
                    String type, String habitat, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.region = region;
        this.pokeNumber = pokeNumber;
        this.species = species;
        this.type = type;
        this.habitat = habitat;
        this.description = description;                   
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public int pokeNumber() {
        return pokeNumber;
    }

    public String getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getHabitat() {
        return habitat;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Pokemon: " + name + "\nRegion: " + region + "\nNational Pokemon #: " + pokeNumber + "\nSpecies: " + species + "\nType: " + type + "\nHabitat: " + habitat + "\nDescription: " + description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Array lists. Wow. I never knew you could do it like that. Thanks!